# combining columns with different queries sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 queries, but I want to combine them into one (with three columns).
[this are my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt4lM.jpg)

this is my code:

```
Select family = count(s.destiny) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car 
where s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'kids') 

Select lux = count(s.destiny) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car
where s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'luxury')

Select sports = count(s.destiny) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car
where s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'sport car')
```

Can you help me combine it into one 'select'?

Comment: Your query is weird . . . Why `s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'kids') ` and not simply `s.destiny = 'kids'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional aggregation seems like this right approach:

```
Select sum(case when density = 'kids' then 1 else 0 end) as family,
       sum(case when density = 'lux' then 1 else 0 end) as luxury,
       sum(case when density = 'sport car' then 1 else 0 end) as sports       
from rental r inner join
     cars s
     on s.number_car = ID_car ;
```

Comment: this is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is:

```
SELECT 
(
Select family = count(s.destiny) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car 
where s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'kids') 
) as kids,
(
Select lux = count(s.destiny) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car
where s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'luxury')
) as luxury,
(
Select sports = count(s.destiny) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car
where s.destiny in (select destiny from cars where destiny like 'sport car')
) as sportsCar
```

That being said, I strongly recommend considering removing the sub-queries here.

Something like this:

```
SELECT destiny, COUNT(1)
FROM cars
GROUP BY destiny
```

Answer (score 0):

why you cant try this ?

```
Select destiny,count(*) from rental
inner join cars as s on s.number_car = ID_car
where s.destiny in ( 'cars','luxury')
group by destiny
```

Comment: in Your code is bug : Incorrect syntax near ','
You can't put comma between 'cars' and 'luxury'. but thank you for your interest :)

Comment: Edited as per Gordon comment